# Not overwriting text file properly (Python)

Tags: python, function, readlines

My program is supposed to take a text file, print the contents, count the lines, ask for a string input, remove every occurrence of that string, say how many times the string was removed, and then output the new contents of the file. We were asked to use one file, not an input and an output file.

My code works and does everything it's supposed to up until I try to store the changes in the file at the end of the char_count function and the print_output function seems to not be working right at all.

If I have an input file of contents:

```
Apples
Oranges
Bananas
Apples
Oranges
Bananas
```

if I try to remove Bananas, the resulting file contents for the input file is:

```
ApplesOrangesApplesOrangesles
Oranges
Bananas
```

I've been trying to figure out what's going on with no progress, and our course textbook doesn't seem to mention overwriting input files, but we're required to do it for an assignment. What is wrong with my last two functions?

```
def main():

    input_file_name = input("Please Enter the name of your text file: ")
    infile = open(input_file_name, "r+")
    print()

    print("---------------------------------------")
    print("THE FILE CONTENTS ARE")
    print("---------------------------------------")
    print_file(infile)
    print("---------------------------------------")
    count_lines(infile)
    print("---------------------------------------")
    input_string = input("Please enter the word or string of words you want to remove from the text file: ")
    print("---------------------------------------")
    char_count(infile, input_string)
    print("---------------------------------------")
    print("THE NEW FILE CONTENTS ARE")
    print_output(infile)
    print("---------------------------------------")

    infile.close()

def print_file(infile):
    infile.seek(0)
    allLines = infile.readlines()
    for line in allLines:
        text = line.rstrip()
        print(text)

def count_lines(infile):
    infile.seek(0)
    allLines = infile.readlines()
    count = 0
    char = " "
    for line in allLines :
        text = line.rstrip()
        while char != "":
            char = infile.read(1)
        count = count + 1
    print("THE NUMBER OF LINES IS: %d " % count)

def char_count(infile, input_string) :
    count = 0
    infile.seek(0)
    allLines = infile.readlines()
    infile.seek(0)
    for line in allLines:
        while input_string in line:
            line = line.replace(input_string, "")
            count = count + 1
        text = line.rstrip()
        infile.write(text)
    print("NUMBER OF OCCURRENCES REMOVED IS: %d" % count)

def print_output(infile):
    infile.seek(0)
    allLines = infile.readlines()
    for line in allLines:
        text = line.rstrip()
        print(text)
main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to truncate the file first to get the required output.

```
def main():

    input_file_name = input("Please Enter the name of your text file: ")
    infile = open(input_file_name, "r+")
    print()

    print("---------------------------------------")
    print("THE FILE CONTENTS ARE")
    print("---------------------------------------")
    print_file(infile)
    print("---------------------------------------")
    count_lines(infile)
    print("---------------------------------------")
    input_string = input("Please enter the word or string of words you want to remove from the text file: ")
    print("---------------------------------------")
    char_count(infile, input_string)
    print("---------------------------------------")
    print("THE NEW FILE CONTENTS ARE")
    print_output(infile)
    print("---------------------------------------")

    infile.close()

def print_file(infile):
    infile.seek(0)
    allLines = infile.readlines()
    for line in allLines:
        text = line.rstrip()
        print(text)

def count_lines(infile):
    infile.seek(0)
    allLines = infile.readlines()
    count = 0
    char = " "
    for line in allLines :
        text = line.rstrip()
        while char != "":
            char = infile.read(1)
        count = count + 1
    print("THE NUMBER OF LINES IS: %d " % count)

def char_count(infile, input_string) :
    count = 0
    infile.seek(0)
    allLines = infile.readlines()
    infile.seek(0)
    infile.truncate() #Empty your file first to rewrite it
    for line in allLines:
        while input_string in line:
            line = line.replace(input_string, "")
            count = count + 1
        text = line.rstrip() 
        if(text != ""):
            infile.write(text + "\n") #To write in multiple lines
    print("NUMBER OF OCCURRENCES REMOVED IS: %d" % count)

def print_output(infile):
    infile.seek(0)
    allLines = infile.readlines()
    for line in allLines:
        text = line.rstrip()
        print(text)
main()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I completely forgot to put in a condition for text there at the end of char_count, and I had .truncate() in there previously but it was in the wrong place.

Comment: Your welcome, And don't forget to accept the answer if you are satisfied with the answer